# Prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\:\left[n+\left(-1\right)^n\right]\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

> Prove that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\:\left[n+\left(-1\right)^n\right]\in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Hey I tried many ways to do this, like the recurrence method, and double recurrence method, but I always get stuck on $(-1)^n$ so I tried to proof that n is always bigger than $-1^n$: $n>-1^n$ for every $n>=1$ but I get stuck on the same thing. I need this just to proof that the set A= $ [{n+ -1^n; n\in \mathbb{N}}]$ = $\mathbb{N}$
Thanks.

Comment: Use dollar signs for math statements

Comment: There is nothing to prove.

Comment: @G.Snapsmath Yes I forgot about them.

Comment: If $\;0\notin\Bbb N\;$ , as many mathematicians consider (and I am one of them), then the claim is false, since $\;1+(-1)^1=0\notin\Bbb N\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I never saw this, why you consider that 0∉N ?

Comment: @AmineMarzouki Is not that deep: it is just that for me a "natural number" is an integer that is also *positive* . But I don't care considering $\;0\in\Bbb N\;$ if that makes like any easier for me in any way...

Comment: @DonAntonio Well you can't change something in math just because it makes things easier for you. that's not how maths work,if you wanna change it, you must have a proof...

Comment: @AmineMarzouki You are wrong: I, and any other more or less well educated, non-deranged, mathematician can change **anything** I want as long as it is either a definition or something that doesn't affect "negatively" anything else in mathematics. The present case is like the former above.

Comment: @DonAntonio then I think you'll have another math of your own. If you can change definitions, everything will become a mess. Just my point of view. But I'd highly appreciate if there's a proof to what you've just said.

Comment: @AmineMarzouki Not at all...and I think you're going to be pretty surprised when you'll find out how many authors out there don't consider zero to be a natural number... In fact, my advice to you is to read about this every time you grab a new book.

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed, I am surprised right now, it's the first time I see someone who don't consider zero to be a natural number. Anyhow, can you answer the question considering zero is actually ∈N. just for the sake of argument.

Comment: @AmineMarzouki It already has been answered, no need to repeat. The following are just a few examples of books where the author doesn't consider zero a natural number: Hijab's "Introduction to Calculus and Classical Analysis", Thomas' "Calculus" (in AP-2), Adams' "Calculus", Yates', "Analytic Geometry with Calculus", Spivak's "Calculus", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can manually check for $0$, $1$ that

$0 + 1 = 1$

$1 - 1 = 0$

Now for even $n \ge 2$, $n + 1 \in \Bbb N $ and for odd $n > 2$, $n - 1 \in \Bbb N $ by closure of $\Bbb N $ under addition.

Edit:
But per your newly added paragraph, this is not the same thing as proving this set is equal to $\Bbb N $, you also need to prove that every $n \in \Bbb N $ also belongs to this set.

---

Update: we have shown that your set is a subset of the natural numbers.  To show equality we must also show the natural numbers are a subset of your set.

So let $m \in \Bbb N $

Now if $m \ge 2$ is even, we set $m = n - 1$ which implies $m + 1 = n $.  But since $m \ge 2$, by closure we know $n \in \Bbb N $ and since $m $ is even then $n $ is odd.  So $m \in$ {$n + ( -1^{n}) | n \in \Bbb N $} for all odd $n \ge 2$

Similarly if $m \ge 2$ is odd, we set $m = n + 1$ which implies $m - 1 = n $. But since $m \ge 2$, by closure we know $n \in \Bbb N $ and since $m $ is odd then $n $ is even. So $m \in$ {$n + ( -1^{n}) | n \in \Bbb N $} for all even $n \in \Bbb N $.

Again we check manually for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$.

This proves that $\Bbb N $ is a subset of your set, hence they are equal.

---

Another way to see this is to write that for our set

$M_n = ${$n + ( -1^{n}) | n \in \Bbb N $}

for all even $2j \ge 2$,

$M_{2j} = ${$3, 5, 7,...$}

and for all odd $2j + 1 \ge 2$

$M_{2j + 1} = ${$2, 4, 6,...$}

Then the union of these sets is {$2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7... $} and if we add the cases of $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ then $M = \Bbb N $

Use whichever is more intuitive to you

Comment: Why ? I thought it was the same thing. You proofed that n-1∈N and n+1∈N and if n=0 or n=1 then it's ∈N. then why we can't conclude that the sets are the same?

Comment: @Amine: If you prove that every element of $A$ is a natural number, you've only proven $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, not necessarily that $A=\Bbb N$. (This, and not the procedure described in your comment, is what Phillip has done in their answer.)

Comment: @EricStucky You're right, but I though since the lim of $n + (-1)^n= \infty $ then A=N, of course with the first condition that is: every element of AA is a natural number.

Comment: No. There could be some integer $m $ which is "jumped over" in the set you have constructed. You need to prove there isn't one.

Comment: @PhillipHamilton yep you're right. I'll think of it, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @Amine Marzouki I'll add an update

Comment: @PhillipHamilton Perfect ! Thank you so much. I used your technique in a question was before I posted this, but it didn't work because the set was $C=\left\{\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n};\:n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ I used S1= $1/2k ; k\in \mathbb{N} $ and $-1/2k+1; k\in \mathbb{N}$ the I found that -1 is neither in those sets.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $a_n=\left[n+\left(-1\right)^n\right]$, then
$$a_{n+2}=a_n+2$$

Comment: would you clarify please?

Comment: @AmineMarzouki $$a_{n+2}=(n+2)+(-1)^{n+2}=(n+2)+(-1)^{n}(-1)^2$$ and use induction....

Answer (score 1):

You really only need to show this holds true for $1$. You also must be assuming $0\in\mathbb{N}$. You can easily argue for natural numbers larger than $1$. since $n-1\ge 1$ for all $n > 1$.